# How do I scrape multi-language web using Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm using Python to scrape data from Japanese website where it offers both English & Japanese language. [Link here](https://data.j-league.or.jp/SFMS01/search?team_ids=33&home_away_select=0)

The problem is I got the data I needed but in the wrong language (Link of both languages are identical). I tried inspecting the html page and saw the element 'lang' as followed:

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">`

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ja" xml:lang="ja" class="">`

Here is the code I used:

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd

url='https://data.j-league.or.jp/SFMS01/search?team_ids=33&home_away_select=0'
page = requests.get(url)
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')
```

```
col = []
i = 0

for t in tr_elements[0]:
    i += 1
    name = t.text_content()
    print("{}".format(name))
    col.append((name,[]))
```

At this point I got the head row of the table from the page but in Japanese version.
I'm new to Python and the scrapy. I don't know if there's any method I could use to get the data in English?
If there is any existing examples, templates or other resources I  could use, that'd be better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: welcome to so, have you tried setting up cookie as the english request of the website sets the cookie to `Set-Cookie: SFCM01LANG=en;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I visited the website you added, so for english it adds a cookie (look at the headers for `Request URL: https://data.j-league.or.jp/SFMS01/search?team_ids=33&home_away_select=0` in network tab), you will see

`Set-Cookie: SFCM01LANG=en; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Tue, 18-Oct-2022 19:14:29 GMT; Path=/`

---

So I have basically used that,
change you code snippet to this

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd

url='https://data.j-league.or.jp/SFMS01/search?team_ids=33&home_away_select=0'
page = requests.get(url, cookies={'SFCM01LANG':'en'})
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')
```

Comment: Can you please explain how did you find that language parameter? How that would apply to other websites?

Comment: this is already written in the answer `look at the headers for Request URL: https://data.j-league.or.jp/SFMS01/search?team_ids=33&home_away_select=0 in network tab`